# How to launch Socket.io API in mocha unit test?

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io, mocha.js, chai

I have a nodejs API project which I am testing with mocha and Chai. I am now trying to develop a socket.io aspect of my API. To test it I have the following test:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000/api/jobs');

describe('Jobs Socket /api/jobs', function () {
    it('Should connect', function (done) {
        socket.on('connect', function () {
            done()
        });
    })
})
```

However, the test times out. I am assuming that this is because my API isn't running in these tests. Despite having already developed quite a lot of REST end points, I haven't paid much attention as to how the API server is being run. I have a `../index.ts` file which includes:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
//var io = require('socket.io')(server);
//server.listen(80);

var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
new RealTimeJobs(io);
```

So this is how the socket it being created, so do I need to call this file somehow from my mocha test?